# Bounding the size of integer solutions of curves $x^{r}+y^{s}=z^{t}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I was reading Poonen's paper "Twists of X(7) and primitive solutions of $x^{2}+y^{3}=z^{7}$ (available [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/pss.pdf)) where he describes how he found all primitive solutions of the above curve.

A solution is said to be primitive if $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$.

I am wondering as an extension of his work suppose you are given an arbitrary curve of the form $x^{r}+y^{s}=z^{t}$ where $\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{t}-1 < 0$ (this implies that there are finitely many integer solutions of the given curve), then my questions are:

- are there any known results which give an upper bound on the maximum *size* of the integer solutions of the given curve, i.e., does $\exists B > 0$ s.t. for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $a^{r}+b^{s}=c^{t}$ then $\max{\{|a|,|b|,|c|\}} < B$?
- is there any reason to think that there is an upper bound on the *size* of the integer solutions as a function of $r,s,t$?